# MySQL - Order by auto relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
tb_objs
-------
obj_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
obj_name varchar(45) NOT NULL
obj_parent int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
```

It`s something like a ordered list... The first element has the 'obj_parent' = null, and the second elemente has 'obj_parent' = id of first element etc etc etc...

So, i want select all elements ordered by obj_parent...
I dont know if i am cleary in what a i want... But the result has to be like this:

```
obj_id   |   obj_name   |   obj_parent
  3      |    first     |      null
  9      |    second    |       3
  1      |    third     |       9
  2      |    fourth    |       1
  4      |    fifth     |       2
  ...
  etc   etc    etc   etc
```

If you take a look... The object 'child' is always after his parent... It`s like a C++ ordered list...

```
obj_parent
obj_id        <------   object_parent
                        obj_id           <------ obj_parent
                                                 obj_id
```

Comment: I don't think I understand, maybe some more data would help.  What you show looks like it could be solved by a ORDER BY obj_parent.  Is your problem that you want NULL 1st and it's being sorted last?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: MySQL really has no built in support for hierarchical/recursive queries.  You either need to do this in a stored procedure.  Or, store the entire parent path to the top parent in each row.

Comment: Tks a lot... You`ve been useful...